# Can anyone crack this Progess Bar?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

Hey I'm using a bootstrap progress bar simple animated model on my website but it's a bit boring.

Does anyone know how to make it look like this?

I can't crack the functions

http://fueled.com/rameet-chawla/

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use css transition to animate the progress bar

```
transition: width 500ms cubic-bezier(0.84, -0.39, 0.38, 1.225);
```

Here's the example: http://codepen.io/katwhocodes/pen/KpvmQR

Comment: Thanks for the code but It's not cutting the edge  of the progress bar in a diagonal =/

Comment: I see. I thought you need the animation. Maybe you can try to add the css shape by using 'progress-bar:after'.

Comment: .progress-bar:after {
      content: '';
      width: 0; 
      height: 0; 
      border-top: 30px solid #337ab7;
      border-right: 30px solid transparent;
      position: absolute;
      right: -20px;
      top: 0;
    } I updated the example code too